# css doesn't work when applying to rectangle class?

Tags: css

I cannot figure out why the style doesn't apply to rectangle.

style

```
 <style>
.bar {
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
    fill: green;
}

</style>
```

svg

```
<body>
<svg width="100" height="100">
<rect class="bar"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

when I change according to joe_young's suggestions, it works in Chrome but not in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    fill: green;
}
</style>
</head>



<body>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect class="bar" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<style>` tags should be in `<head>` tags, and there should be a `</html>` at the end of your code - try that

Comment: I delete them just to simplify the code. Still it doesn't work...

Comment: That is odd, because it is working for me. What are you doing this on; is it a website I can look at? In what way is the style not being applied?

Comment: It works in chrome but not in firefox, which is really odd

Comment: Turns out that firefox doesn't like having the SVG's styles in the `<style>` tags. See [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38313801/4206206) (you need to inline the styles: `<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect class="bar" width="100" height="100px" style="fill: green"/>
</svg>`)

Comment: That solves my problem. Could you tell me where can I find those rules?

Comment: I'm afraid I just got the by trial-and-error; generally you're completely fine (and it is advised) to put normal elements' styles in `<style>` tags (or even in an external stylesheet), but I suppose that with SVG it is different. I would think anyway that it was easier to inline just your SVG's styles - there's no harm in that, so that's what I would do. As for your question, again, I'm sorry I don't have any hard-and-fast rules for circumsstances like this, you've just got to play around, have a think about what *could* be causing the problem, and try out lots of different solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As for your problem, turns out that firefox doesn't like the SVG's styles in the `<style>` tags, you need to inline them:*

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect class="bar" width="100" height="100px" style="fill: green"/>
</svg>
```

---

You're trying to use an SVG element, `<rect>`, so it needs to go within the `<svg>` tags
Also, when using it with CSS (as you're doing here), your width and height values need a unit, here `px`

```css
.bar {
  width: 100px;   /* You need to include the 'px' here'*/
  height: 100px;
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect class="bar" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! but it still doesn't work. I edit my question according to your advice.

Answer (score -1):

It needs to be enclosed in an `svg` tag.

[Reference for further reading.](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_rect.asp)